# Accessing color_attributes for every vertex in Blender script

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-colors

How can I access the `color_attribute` stored for each vertex and store it in an array using Python in Blender 3.4? Using `vertex_colors` does no longer work (it gives an error that no vertex_colors are stored). In the Blender API it points to using color_attributes instead. How can I access the rgb values stored for each vertex and store them in an array?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is through

```
o.data.color_attributes['Color']
```

where 'Color' is the name of your color attribute.

From that, you have

```
o.data.color_attributes['Color'].domain
```

which can be either 'CORNER' or 'POINT' (respectively 'per face vertex color' or 'per vertex color').

Continuing

```
o.data.color_attributes['Color'].data[XXX].color[YYY]
```

where `XXX` is the vertex (or the face corner, ie per face) and `YYY` is the color component (rgb, etc.).

All this is new... not sure to be able to add more details about that...